# How does PHP copy() handle memory

Tags: php, file, memory-management

I need to use PHP's `copy()` function to copy files from one location to another.  I am intentionally not using `rename()`.

The files are 500MB to 1GB.  It seems that it takes about 10-20 seconds to move them after I start the PHP script (one file is handled per execution).

My server was rejecting the upload of these files because of `max_execution_time`, `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize` and `memory_limit` values, all of which are set ridiculously high, but the server would just time out when I was trying to upload.

Now I'm concerned the server will fail if this `copy()` operation is running while the site is dealing with a lot of traffic.

So my question is, does PHP's `copy()` operate in a way that would overload the server's memory and/or execution time limits?

I know that the PHP script takes a lot of time to complete, but my hope is that the time is essentially just a period of low-memory "waiting time" as PHP sits back and lets the server OS move the file...  I wouldn't think that PHP would need to load the file into a buffer or anything like that in order to copy it, but memory discussion on this level is a topic a bit out of my understanding.

Can anyone explain how PHP `copy()` uses memory, and if there are any risks associated with memory overloads?

Comment: copy i suspect would use the os function (which of course is an option for you also) it would not read the whole file in to memory

Comment: I don't know the internals, but `copy()` should not need much memory. Usually file copying, if not completely delegated to OS routines, just uses a small buffer of some kb to get a reasonable overhead of read and write system calls. The most IO buffering will be done by the filesystem caches which are out of PHP's sight and not affected by `memory_limit`. However, plenty of things are a little akward with PHP, so copy() maybe either.

Comment: It seems at some point in history `copy()` did use up too much memory doing something awkward: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29922

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [the source](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/standard/file.c#1599) for `copy`, [it](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/standard/file.c#php_copy_file_ctx) [works](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/main/php_streams.h#438) [ultimately](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/main/streams/streams.c#1487) by reading and writing chunks of [8KB size](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/main/streams/php_streams_int.h#49) -- so it won't end up allocating a whole lot of the server's memory. This is of course what one would expect to happen, as people have already commented.

However, multiple copies of big files running in parallel can easily kill the performance of the storage medium (especially if it's made of spinning rust), which in turn can lead to the copies taking ridiculous amounts of time to complete. This could easily turn out to be longer than the script's max execution time limit, so it would be a good idea to remove the limit before starting the copy.

Comment: safer\esier\ more efficent to call the OS copy function you think?

Comment: @Dagon: You can't call an OS file-level copy function directly (one might not even exist). You can spawn an external process that does the copy, but I 'm not sure if you can count on that being faster. It would certainly make it more difficult to see what went wrong in case of an error.

Comment: I'll give it a shot on the higher load server and see if it causes any issues, thanks.  There should only be 1 file being copied at a time, so it sounds like I'll be OK.